# Perform map method on model object Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I queried `@ingredient = Feed.find(params[:ingredient_id])` and it returned a model hash object like

```
< Feed id: 1, ingredient: "Sorghum, Grain", cost_kg: 26.0, d_m: 88.0, c_p: 11.0, m_e: 3212.0, c_f: 2.3, e_e: 2.1, ash: 2.6, ca: nil, p:
0.32, lys: 0.22, met: 0.15, trp: 0.17, created_at: "2016-01-26 12:54:05", updated_at: "2016-01-26 12:54:05">
```

I want to take divide all the `float values`, in the response  with `2` . Please pardon me if it sounds creepy :P

I tried to  do it through `map/select` combination but couldn't succeed

Answer (score 3):

You can get float type by `columns_hash` method

call `Feed.column_hash` -> You can get all column infomation

Somthing like, (depend on your db adapter)

```
> Reservation.columns_hash['price_amount']
=> #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x007fd0ca931a78
 @array=false,
 @cast_type=
  #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Float:0x007fd0b235d420
   @limit=nil,
   @precision=nil,
   @scale=nil>,
 @default=nil,
 @default_function=nil,
 @name="price_amount",
 @null=true,
 @sql_type="double precision">
```

you can get float type by `sql_type` or class name of `cast_type`
So, you can get float column

```
float_columns = Feed.columns_hash.select { |_k, v| v.cast_type.class.name.include? 'Float' }
```

and divide

```
feed = Feed.find(params[:ingredient_id])
float_columns.keys.each do |attr|
  feed[attr] = feed[attr] / 2 unless feed[attr].nil?
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
@ingredient.attributes.each do |key, value|
  if value.is_a? Float
    @ingredient[key] = value / 2
  end
end
```

This code iterates over attributes of `@ingredient` object and if an attribute is a Float, then divides it by 2 and reassign new attribute value back to `@ingredient`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ingredient =    Feed.find(params[:ingredient_id]) 

@ingredient
  .attributes
  .symbolize_keys
  .delete_if { |k| [:updated_at, :created_at, :id, :ingredient].include?(k) }
  .map{ |k, v| { k => v.to_f / 2 } }
```

this will return

```
[{:cost_kg=>13.0}, {:d_m=>44.0}, {:c_p=>5.5}, {:m_e=>1606.0}, {:c_f=>1.15}, {:e_e=>1.05}, {:ash=>1.3}, {:ca=>0.0}, {:p=>0.16}, {:lys=>0.11}, {:met=>0.075}, {:trp=>0.085}]
```

Comment: that is wrong because takes all attributes. If Feed object has text attribute or foreign key it brings error

Comment: yes Agree Selme, he can just white list the attributes he wants with `select` to instead of blacklisting with `delete_if`. In worst case scenario you can add one more `delete_if`   after the first `delete_if` that would do: `.delete_if { |k,v| v.to_f == 0.0  }`  in which  `"nonsense".to_f == 0.0`